# Kotlin, text does not appear on buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

i got two buttons in android app layout(kotlin language). The problem is that text does not appear on the button, like on the screenshot.
[Screenshot(click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuRAg.png) What can i do to fix this? I can't find anything about this problem on the internet.

Comment: Why is your Button tag showing red in IDE ? Also have u tried running it on a device/emulator ?

Comment: @ADM i repaired that red tag on button(i did not import something), i ran it only on emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the Button is on red. Please edit your question with the complete XML file as screenshot or text. If text is not appearing also when the button is not red marked, check which theme are you using. Test it toggling themes on Theme on Preview in the Preview window in the XML file.

Comment: Changing theme worked, thank you!